# Need to filter my sql results for the last 4 days

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need my filter to return only the last 4 days from the current date. My struggle has been in properly using the DATEADD() and NOW() functions because I keep keeping getting errors. Any advice?

As of now this is my SQL statement:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS COUNT, DATE(CREATED_AT) AS CREATED_AT
FROM ACCOUNT
GROUP BY DATE(CREATED_AT)
ORDER BY CREATED_AT ASC
```

The output is this:

```
"result": [
    {
      "count": "1",
      "created_at": "2016-11-12T06:00:00.000Z"
    },
    {
      "count": "2",
      "created_at": "2016-11-13T06:00:00.000Z"
    },
    {
      "count": "1",
      "created_at": "2016-11-14T06:00:00.000Z"
    },
    {
      "count": "2",
      "created_at": "2016-11-15T06:00:00.000Z"
    }
  ],
```

Edit: I am using POSTGRES and I think that changes the kind of functions I can use to identify date.

Answer (score 0):

You just want a simple `WHERE` clause.  Assuming you have no future dates:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS COUNT, DATE(CREATED_AT) AS CREATED_AT
FROM ACCOUNT
WHERE CREATED_AT >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 4 day)
GROUP BY DATE(CREATED_AT)
ORDER BY CREATED_AT ASC;
```

Comment: the date_sub function didn't work for me, I just edited the original post. I am thinking maybe its because I am using postgres

Answer (score 0):

After doing some research I found a POSTGRES friendly version that works!

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS COUNT, 
DATE(CREATED_AT) AS CREATED_AT 
FROM ACCOUNT WHERE CREATED_AT >= NOW() - INTERVAL '4 DAYS' 
GROUP BY DATE(CREATED_AT) 
ORDER BY CREATED_AT ASC
```